# C# - Generic method failing to return Enum value

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have a problem here, with a generic method that is supposed to return an `Enum` value from a generic `enum` type.

The code is available in https://github.com/aibarralandeo/StackOverflowIssues

I will explain the scenario in more detail. I have a class that will acts a base class for manage classes 'chains'. (In the repo you will find more code detail, but I will show here the most important parts).

```
public class BaseNestedNode
    {
        private int searchedIndex;

        private BaseNestedNode parentObject;
        private BaseNestedNode childObject;

        private Enum currentNode;

        private Dictionary<int, Type> typesList = new Dictionary<int, Type>();
        private Type evaluationEnum;
        private NodeType nodeType;

        public BaseNestedNode(int searchedIndex)
        {
            this.searchedIndex = searchedIndex;
        }

        public void SetEvaluationEnum(Type evaluationType)
        {
            if (evaluationType.IsEnum)
            {
                evaluationEnum = evaluationType;
                //SetCurrentNode(Demo.ToEnumSafe<evaluationEnum>(searchedIndex));
            }
        }

        public void AddTypeToList(Type compareType, int key)
        {
            if (compareType.IsEnum)
                typesList.Add(key, compareType.GetType());
        }

        public void Evaluate()
        {
            if (!IsChild()) return;

            var parentType = parentObject.GetCurrentNode();
            evaluationEnum = typesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == Demo.EnumToInt(parentType)).Value;

            //var value = EnumerationHelpers.ToEnumSafe<Convert.ChangeType(rrre, evaluationEnum)>(searchedIndex);
        }

        public Type GetEvaluationEnum() => evaluationEnum;

        public int GetSearchedIndex() => searchedIndex;

        public bool IsChild() => nodeType == NodeType.Child;

        public Enum GetCurrentNode() => currentNode;

        public Enum GetNextNode() => childNode;

        public void SetCurrentNode(Enum node) => currentNode = node;

        public void SetChildNode(Enum node) => childNode = node;

        public void SetParentObject(BaseNestedNode parent)
        {
            if (parentObject != parent)
            {
                parentObject = parent;
                parent.SetChildObject(this);
                this.nodeType = NodeType.Child;
            }
        }
        public void SetChildObject(BaseNestedNode child)
        {
            if (childObject != child)
            {
                childObject = child;
                child.SetParentObject(this);
            }
        }

        public Enum GetParentNode()
        {
            return (parentObject == null) ? null : parentObject.GetCurrentNode();
        }
    }
```

And I have these enums:

```
public enum NodeType
    {
        Parent = 1,
        Child = 2
    }

    public enum TestEnum
    {
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2,
        Value3 = 3
    }

    public enum TestEnum2
    {
        Value11 = 10,
        Value20 = 11,
        Value50 = 30,
    }

    public enum TestEnum3
    {
        Value5432 = 81290,
        Value31 = 38129,
        Value433 = 832190,
    }
```

The intention is to create a class that inherits `BaseNestedNode` and use `SetEvaluationEnum` to establish the `enum` type that that class will use and the current `Enum` value based on the `searchedIndex` private field established when constructed.

That class would act as a parent class, who could be used in other classes who inherits from `BaseNestedNode` to set as the parent using `SetParentObject` method.

`AddTypeToList` is a special method used by childs and when the private field `evaluationEnum` is not set. The purpose to this method is add `enum` Types to a `Dictionary` with the integer value of an specific `Enum` value of a referenced `enum` (check the code to understand better).

After this, `Evaluate` method should be called. In case of be child, the method would use `GetCurrentNode`
method from parent's object to get the actual `Enum` value stablished in private `currentNode` parent's field. The purpose of this is to get it's `integer` value to send it to a generic method (that's the one that is causing me problems).

This method was taken from another StackOverflow answer to get an `Enum` type from generic `enum` using it's `int` value:

```
public static T? ToEnumSafe<T>(this int s) where T : struct
        {
            return (IsEnum<T>(s) ? (T?)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s.ToString()) : null);
        }
```

In summary: I expect to hold an `Enum` value (i.e. `TestEnum.Value1`) in a private field in `BaseNestedNode` class, and use it to compare against a dictionary populated by `AddTypeToList` to be able to set in a child class this field with another `enum` based on the selection of the parent's selection.

If you have any questions or it was not clear, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In C# 7.3 you can now use `where T : Enum, struct` as a type constraint, btw.

Comment: Also, your code will fail for enums that use `Int64` or `UInt64` as their underlying type.

Comment: You don't need to use dodgy hacks like `Enum.Parse( numericValue.ToString() )` - instead you can take advantage of the fact that all enums implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: The Enum.Parse will parse the name of the Enum, not it's value, to convert int to Enum you should just cast it. But the universal way requires boxing (T?)(object)s;

Comment: Yes, I already tried that too. If you go to the link and copy the code of the Program.cs file to overwrite the code of a new console app, you will be able to test this entirely

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo Please look at this `EnumTraits<T>` class I wrote that I believe provides the functionality you're looking for without using any ugly workarounds: https://gist.github.com/Jehoel/aa07ceda23b2ca03184722c3f63ce7ca